# Save rows of Dataframe to Separate txt files

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe

Output displayed on the terminal screen has to be saved into seperate txt files. The output terminal looks like this:

```
A1001
2
B1001
6
C1001
4
```

which has been derived from a while loop via commands:

```
print(apartmentno)
print(df)
```

How can I print each pair of output into a text file named output1.txt, output2.txt, output3.txt.... outputn.txt?

Expected output:

output1.txt

```
A1001
2
```

output2.txt

```
B1001
6
```

output3.txt

```
C1001
4
```

So far I have tried the following code:

```
.
.
.
df = disp_date.ClassAttend.sum()
print(apartmentno)
print(final_df)

z = []
z.append(apartmentno)
z.append(df)
print(z)

ctr = 0
for i in z:
   ctr += 1
   f = open(('d:\\output'+ str(ctr)+ '.txt'), mode='w') 
   f.write(apartmentno)
   f.write(df)
   f.close()
```

Also, I get an error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory although I am opening in 'w' mode.

How can I get my required output?

Comment: put save block code inside loop that you using for printing data, and use f = open('output'+str(ctr)+'.txt",'w') for saving files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me how you are constructing your loop, but hopefully the following information is helpful to you.

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for the index numbers in your loop, and use the [with](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) keyword when dealing with file objects. This way you can create your files. Regarding `with`:

> The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point.

As of Python 3.6, you can also use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting), which makes the construction of your filename more readable:

```
for index, value in enumerate(z):
    with open(f'output{index}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(value)
```